# SVG does not display when attached into TD via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, svg, size

I have simple HTML:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="mytd"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And here's JavaScript code:

```
var svg = document.createElement('SVG');
svg.setAttribute('width', '100');
svg.setAttribute('height', '100');    

var circle = document.createElement('CIRCLE');
circle.setAttribute('cx', '50');
circle.setAttribute('cy', '50');
circle.setAttribute('r', '50');
circle.setAttribute('stroke', 'green');
circle.setAttribute('fill', 'green');

svg.appendChild(circle);

document.getElementById('mytd').appendChild(svg);
```

Now it appears that SVG gets inserted into my TD, but its size is 0x0, instead of 100x100 as I set it. What's the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all `svg` elements, you have to use:

```
document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tagName)
```

...instead of the regular `document.createElement`.

---

### Demo Snippet

```js
var ns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'

var svg = document.createElementNS(ns, 'svg');
svg.setAttribute('width', '100');
svg.setAttribute('height', '100');    

var circle = document.createElementNS(ns, 'circle');
circle.setAttribute('cx', '50');
circle.setAttribute('cy', '50');
circle.setAttribute('r', '50');
circle.setAttribute('stroke', 'green');
circle.setAttribute('fill', 'green');

svg.appendChild(circle);

document.getElementById('mytd').appendChild(svg);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="mytd"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I did, I had to wait 7 minutes to be able to accept

Answer (score -1):

Try adding in  element:

```
viewBox="0 0 105 105"
```